# Golang Import (undefined: Request)

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a custom function that passes the Request object back as a result:

```
 func ConstructRequest(testParameters string, reqType string) Request {
    req, err := http.NewRequest(reqType, testPath+testParameters, nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil
    } else {
        return req
    }
}
```

but I'm getting a "undefined: Request" error

I'm not sure what library I need to import to make it work?

Comment: Shouldn't you add a type to the `testParameters, reqType` parameters? like `func ConstructRequest(testParameters, reqType string) *Request`

Comment: sorry i just corrected it

Comment: And should,'t you add the package associated with Request in your function definition? Like http.Request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`undefined: Request` seems normal if you don't specify the package for the returned type:

```
func ConstructRequest(testParameters string, reqType string) http.Request
                                                             ^^^^
```

Since [`http.NewRequest()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest) returns a pointer, this should be:

```
func ConstructRequest(testParameters string, reqType string) *http.Request
```

Comment: calculation_test.go:18:64: expected ';', found '*'